# How to implement Cycle counting in Modelica?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have a battery model in Modelica. PNet is the value of power flowing through battery (PNet is positive for charging and negative for discharging). This oscillates based on a load. I want to calculate the number of cycles that the battery is put through and also the depth of discharge comin in from each of these cycles.

Answer (score 5):

This is a pretty generic question so my answer will be rather generic as well. Also it is not clear to me, what you are referring to as a cycle. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_cycle) mentions deep and shallow discharge and there are some others as well.

Some general note: In Modelica the `when` statement is useful for counting. You can read through Section 8.3.5 of the [Modelica Language Specification](https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf) to get full information on this.

The below examples computes how often the variable `PNet` turns positive, which should respond to the number of shallow cycles above. Some description for the model:

- The model `noiseSource` computes a random number which is then filtered by a first order (PT1) element to compute PNet. The filter should likely be skipped in the original example, it is only there to smooth the trajectory a bit.
- The code in the `when` statement is executed **once** at the time when the condition turns true, which enables the counting.
- The `pre` statement accesses the value of `cycles` right before the `when` statement got active, which enables counting how often the condition occurred.
- The `start=0` in `cycles(start=0)` sets the starting value for the variable `cycles`, which is necessary as you cannot use `cycles = 0` as this would generate an equation for cycles, which is not what you want.
- The `inner` model `globalSeed` is necessary for the noiseSource to work.

Here is the actual code:

```
model CycleCounter
  inner Modelica.Blocks.Noise.GlobalSeed globalSeed;
  Modelica.Blocks.Noise.NormalNoise noiseSource;

  parameter Modelica.SIunits.Time T = 1e-3 "Time constant of PT1 element to filter random signal to compute PNet";

  Integer cycles(start=0) "Counts the number of ";
  Real PNet "Random value";

equation 
  der(PNet) = (noiseSource.y - PNet)/T;

  when PNet > 0 then
    cycles = pre(cycles)+1;
  end when;

  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="3.2.3")));
end CycleCounter;
```

And the result from simulating in Dymola:

[image: Result of the code above]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! But,unfortunately this model did not work for me as my simulation says "Failed DAE Index"I guess this is because in my case, PNet is actually calculated through derivative of another function, the charge, ENet. And I guess Modelica has some issue calculating double differentials.

Comment: I was able to solve this using zero crossing function though. I just programmed a counter to activate whenever PNet crosses 0 i.e. whenever the battery changes from charging to discharging.

Comment: Modelica is just the language, so to be precise the Modelica tool - presumably OpenModelica in your case - fails to compute the differential. And in your case you would not have to use the filter, which corresponds to the line `der(PNet) = (noiseSource.y - PNet)/T;`. I just added it, as the output of the random source is not very representative of a battery power.